# Replace li navigation menu text with image & keep hover + drop down menu effects?

Tags: html, image, drop-down-menu, css

I'm currently working on a navigation menu that uses `<li>` to construct the bar.  Currently, my menu is working perfectly but I'm wanting to actually REPLACE the text on my menu (i.e. Projects, Compliance, Summary, etc) with actual image buttons that I designed in Photoshop to give it a more aesthetic appeal.

What I have tried:

```
#cssmenu .active {
    background: url("images/DropDown-Design2_02.jpg") no-repeat top left;
}
```

This actually makes my image show up in the desired spot, however you can still see the menu text above the image and when you hover over the portion of the image that's visible, there is no hover effect as there is for the menu items text.

[See this image](http://i.imgur.com/ahBuMLE.png)

My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>


   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>UC Client Login</title>


</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>

<a href="https://www.insurancetrackingservices.com/ITSLive/livehelp.php?department=1" target="_blank"><img border="0" alt="Live Chat" src="images/DropDown-Design2_10.jpg" width="134" height="50"
onmouseover="this.src='images/livechathover.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='images/DropDown-Design2_10.jpg'"></a>

   <li class="space1">Space Gap</li>
   <li class="space2">Space Gap</li>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Projects</span></a>
   <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Select Project</span></a></li>         
         <li class='last'><a href='ActiveVendorBranchRpt.asp'><span>Status By Project</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Compliance</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='ProblemsSpecificRpt.asp'><span>Insured Search</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='NoProblemsRpt.asp'><span>Compliant</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='DeficiencyRpt.asp'><span>Non-Compliant</span></a></li>         
         <li><a href='CancellationRpt.asp'><span>Cancelled</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='InsRateRpt.asp'><span>AM Best</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Contracts</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='../ITSContracts/SummaryOfContracts.aspx'><span>Summary of Contracts</span></a></li>         
         <li><a href='AddContract.asp'><span>Add a Contract</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='../ITSContracts/ContractReport.aspx'><span>Locate a Contract</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Summary</span></a>
   <ul>
         <li><a href='SummaryProblemsRpt.asp'><span>Summary Problems</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='ImproperCoverRpt.asp'><span>Coverages</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='ExpiredCertificatesRpt.asp'><span>Expirations</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='BasicComplRpt.asp'><span>Special Issues</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='MissingPolicyRpt.asp'><span>Missing Policies</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
<!-- ImageReady Slices (DropDown Design2.psd) -->
<div id="Table_01">
  <div id="DropDown-Design2-11">
    <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_11.jpg" width="347" height="166" alt="">
  </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-12">
      <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_12.jpg" width="103" height="142" alt="">
  </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-13">
      <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_13.jpg" width="223" height="166" alt="">
  </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-14">
      <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_14.jpg" width="191" height="166" alt="">
  </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-15">
      <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_15.jpg" width="103" height="24" alt="">
  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute; top:197px; left:374px;"><a target=Bottom href="LogOut.asp"><Font face = Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif size = 1.5 color="1f497d"><b>LOG OUT</b></Font></a></div>

<a href="http://instracking.com/contact_insurance_tracking_services.html" target="_blank"><img border="0" alt="Contact Us" src="images/DropDown-Design2_01.jpg"
onmouseover="this.src='images/contactushover.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='images/DropDown-Design2_01.jpg'"></a> </a>   

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);
/* Menu CSS */#cssmenu,
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url(images/highlight-bg.png) no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;  

}

#cssmenu:before,
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:before,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}

li.space1{
    visibility: hidden;
}

li.space2{
    visibility: hidden;
}

#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url(images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px 26px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #9e3825;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(116, 37, 2, 0.7);
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-right: 14px;

}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,#cssmenu > ul > li:hover.active > a {
  background: url(images/hover.png) repeat;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #97321f;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(122, 42, 26, 0.64);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:active {
  background: url(images/active.png) no-repeat;
}
/* Childs */
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  background: url(images/highlight-bg.png) repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 52px;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a {
  padding: 18px 26px;
  display: block;
  color: #393939;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 150px;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.01 ease-in-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a:hover {
  border-left: 4px solid #de553b;
  background: url(images/hover.png) repeat;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a:active {
  background: url(images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat;
}

#cssmenu .active {
    background: url("images/DropDown-Design2_02.jpg") no-repeat top left;
    }

#Table_01 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:1px;
    width:864px;
    height:1px;
    visibility: inherit;
}


#DropDown-Design2-11 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:50px;
    width:347px;
    height:166px;
}

#DropDown-Design2-12 {
    position:absolute;
    left:347px;
    top:50px;
    width:103px;
    height:142px;
}

#DropDown-Design2-13 {
    position:absolute;
    left:450px;
    top:50px;
    width:223px;
    height:166px;
}

#DropDown-Design2-14 {
    position:absolute;
    left:673px;
    top:50px;
    width:191px;
    height:166px;
}

#DropDown-Design2-15 {
    position:absolute;
    left:347px;
    top:192px;
    width:103px;
    height:24px;
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, only `li` can be children of `ul`.

Comment: Okay so how do you suggest I move forward with being able to use these images and retain the drop down menu + hover effects instead of the text?

Comment: Honestly...  this markup is so messy, that you are just burying yourself.   The amount of CSS you have for this is insane.  You are also way over-qualifying the selectors.  And why are you using inline javascript for hover effects??  Thats what CSS is for.

You really should start from scratch and recode this much cleaner.  You will probably get the desired results much quicker, and if you still have an issue, it will be much easier to troubleshoot.

Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to do a `display:none` on the `<span>Projects</span>` element. You can use [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to swap your text out of view when you hover over it. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: I'm simply answering his question. Of course there are better ways to do this but maybe he wants a quick fix given the code that he already has.

Comment: So then I would assume that when you take your car to the mechanic, you really don't want them to suggest the proper repair...  you'd rather them hand you a roll of duct tape and say 'try this'?

Comment: Your taking the question at face value. I see it as more of "How can I manipulate the DOM?" and "How can I manipulate CSS". Heck, maybe I can learn from this as well. What exactly is so horrendous about my answer? What do you propose aside from starting from scratch? We've all write bad code at one time or another.

Comment: Well if you have any other suggestions Sean aside from "start all over" I'm all ears. @coderrick - any way to have the text permanently be invisible?

Comment: If you look at the JQuery link it has info about .css() which is an event that can be used to change css properties. Then again you maybe able to remove `<span>Projects</span>` complete, I'm not sure why you need it?

Comment: Not quite, I want the text to be permanently hidden or gone that way the image serves as the new button and will be able to trigger the drop down menu.

Comment: @coderrick You shouldn't need to 'manipulate the dom' for a simple nav dropdown.  All that says is you either don't understand CSS, or you are doing something clearly wrong in your markup.  If you want to hide the html text, all you have to do as add `text-indent: -9999px;` to the a tags in the menu.  But again, the code is such a mess, that even if that fixed the issue, its still a huge mess.  @CoryRamirez If you still need help later on today, if I have some time I would be happy to code you up a cleaner, working nav if interested.

Comment: @SeanStopnik Yes that would be fantastic.  I'm learning as I go here, so if you can help me get this working in a more clean way I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I actually just kind of got it to work by completely deleting the text inside <span>Projects</span> and by adding padding in the css; but the hover space doesn't go across the whole image.

Comment: If you're able to help me figure out why the mouse pointer only turns into the little "hand icon" that occurs when you hover over something clickable on a small portion of the image then sure :D

Comment: Piece of cake, the cursor only turns into a hand pointer when your hovering over a hyperlink. I don't know which image your a talking about but it probably has an `<a>` as it parent or it child element. You can set the cursor by doing `element{cursor: pointer;}` more property values can be seen http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: I just figured that out only moments before you answered, but I'll give it to you anyways :)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Again... these are all TOTALLY wrong answers.  DO NOT force the cursor to pointer... if will work correctly when you have your code correct!  Im sorry @coderrick, but you are seriously giving terrible advice.  Cory, you should not remove the html text in the menu... that will totally negate SEO.  You need to just indent it.  Also, your menu a tag needs to be set to `display: block;` to give it positioning.  Therefore giving you a 'little hand' cursor.

Comment: @CoryRamirez What is your email address?  I'll send you a complete working nav.

Comment: @SeanStopnik That would be great, I'm all for more efficient coding.  What is your email?  I'd prefer not to display mine publicly.

Comment: @CoryRamirez You can get mine from my site, which is my firstnamelastname dot com.  Email me there, and I can show you how you can be doing it much more efficiently.